# Laravel v5.2.* (v5.2.29) Auth::guard('api')->attempt($user) fatal error

Tags: php, laravel

Has anyone encountered this problem

```
dd($this->user->check()); return false
```

but

```
Auth::guard('user')->attempt(App\User::find(1))
```

return the error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()

Please help to resolve this problem.

Comment: dd(Auth::guard('user')->check())

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this problem

In `config/auth.php` configuration:

```
'user' => [
    'driver' => 'token',
    'provider' => 'userProvider',
],
```

We need to change to:

```
'user' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
    'provider' => 'userProvider',
],
```

Because `Auth::guard` data is stored in the session

And further work on the well-known scheme

```
Auth::login() = Auth::guard('user')->login()
Auth::attempt() = Auth::guard('user')->attempt()
Auth::user() = Auth::guard('user')->user()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To the function `attempt` you shall pass an array of creditianals, not a user object.

For example:

```
Auth::guard('user')->attempt([
    'email' => 'some@email.com',
    'password' => '1234'
]);
```

And if you are using Laravel and need to authenticate the user, you can call similar:

```
auth()->attempt([
    'email' => 'some@email.com',
    'password' => '1234'
]);
```

Comment: I know.But The documentation says that I can use Auth::guard('api')->attempt(),Auth::guard('any')->attempt(),->login() etc for multiple authentication.