# laravel login through API using token

Tags: php, laravel, token, guard

I'm using laravel 5.4 to develop an api

When trying to login using API Controller

```
Route::post('/login','Auth\ApiLoginController@login')

class ApiLoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:6',
        ]);

        /*return response([
            'email' =>$request->email,
            'password'=> $request->password
        ],200);*/

        if(Auth::guard('api')->attempt(['email'=> $request->email, 'password'=> $request->password], $request->remember)){
            //return redirect()->intended(route('admin.dashboard'));
                return response([
                'data' =>"login successfully"
            ], 200);
        }    

        //return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email','remember'));
            return response([
            'data' =>"login failed"
        ],200);
    } 
}
```

It gives me following error:

> {FatalThrowableError Call to undefined method
>   Illuminate\Auth\TokenGuard::attempt()}

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36673219/2276383

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `config/auth.php`,

**change:**

```
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'token',
],
```

**To:**

```
'api' => [
    'driver' => 'session',
],
```

Because `Auth::guard` data is stored in the session

Comment: Can you explain why this is when the API environment typically doesn't (and shouldn't) use sessions at all?